# Trying to use jquery append after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that sorts table rows when column names are clicked.

I want to append a triangle to the end of the column name that is clicked to show which column the table is sorted on.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.data-table a').click(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            $('body').load('http://mysite.com/index.php/site/table/index/' + $(this).attr('id')).ajaxComplete(function(){
                el.append('&#9650;');
            });
           return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The table sorts correctly, but I can't append the HTML entity to the end of the column name.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Why would you chain on a ajaxComplete, just use the callback

Comment: `el` no longer exists because you replaced it with .load. If you're going to replace the body, why not just do a full page refresh?

Comment: @KevinB i dont think that what you say is correct . el = this , please care to explain more !

Comment: `el` is the anchor tag that was clicked. the anchor tag must be a child of the body. .load replaced everything inside the body, hence why the anchor tag is getting replaced. the element referenced by `this` no longer exists, other than in that one variable. Modifying that variable won't do anything unless you append it back to the DOM.

Comment: @KevinB aha ..  thanks for bringing my attention to that . much obliged :)

Comment: See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/ZbTPv/1/#&togetherjs=JTNRHrDlLE

Comment: @KevinB I want the sorting to seem "seamless". Also, I want to mark the sorted column (with the HTML entity) without altering the URL.

Comment: @symlynk Try just replacing the `tbody` of your sortable table then, or at least something less than the entire `body`.

Comment: replacing the body won't be any more seamless than refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're killing the "body" element with that load statement. Try something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.data-table a').click(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            $('#target_element').load('http://mysite.com/index.php/site/table/index/' + $(this).attr('id')).ajaxComplete(function(){
                el.append('&#9650;');
            });
           return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where "#target_element" refers to the place *in the content* whose contents will be replaced with the results of your ajax request.

Comment: Or just look up the spot for the arrow again. `$('.data-table a').append('&#9650;');` which should do exactly what OP's code does but ... why append to an `<a>` element?

Comment: @jvenema this is in CodeIgniter and I want to use the same view.